# How to speed up the scrollbar

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a ListBox by clicking on repeatButton need to increase the size 2.
or simply increase the step in 3\4 time?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? It's hard to understand what you want exactly (probably that's why you didn't get an answer yet).

Answer (score 1):

The rate at which a `RepeatButton` repeats is controlled by the `RepeatButton.Interval` property.  See [RepeatButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746649%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more details.